# Looking for Struct Keys in Session

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to write a session helper and facing to problem to test if a Struct key in session exists?

I am trying like

```
<cffunction name="Exists" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean" >
    <cfargument name="Key" required="true" type="Any" />
    <cfreturn Evaluate( "StructKeyExists( Session, #Arguments.Key# )" ) />
</cffunction>
```

Where I am calling the function like

```
<cfif Exists("data.fromdate") >
 ...
</cfif>
```

How should I write it?

Thanks

Comment: FYI this type of question should be posted to here: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit of creating your own Exists() function when you can simply use StructKeyExists(session, key) to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: _"I am trying to write a session helper"_ - WHY!?  What problem are you trying to solve, and why isn't `StructKeyExists` (alone) good enough?

Comment: It sounds like he wants a helper function that calls structKeyExists() repeatedly based on a `path.to.a.nested.key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will check any depth struct, and also correctly locks the Session scope.

```
<cffunction name="Exists" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean">
    <cfargument name="Key" required="true" type="string">

    <cfset local.mainKeyList = ListChangeDelims(ListDeleteAt(Arguments.Key, ListLen(Arguments.Key, "."), "."), ",", ".")>

    <cfset local.StructChain = "Session">
    <cfloop list="#local.mainKeyList#" index="local.CurrentKey">
        <cfset local.StructChain &= '["#local.CurrentKey#"]'>
    </cfloop>

    <cflock scope="session" type="readonly" timeout="3">
        <cftry>
            <cfset local.Exists = StructKeyExists(Evaluate(local.StructChain), ListLast(Arguments.Key, "."))>

            <cfcatch>
                <cfset local.Exists = false>
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cflock>

    <cfreturn local.Exists>
</cffunction>

<cflock scope="session" type="exclusive" timeout="3">
    <cfset Session.data.log.deep = "I'm here!">
</cflock>
<cfoutput>#Exists("data.log.deep")#</cfoutput>
```

Hopefully the amount of code in this function will justify why a helper function would be useful, to those pondering your reasons.  This doesn't currently, but could be enhanced to, deal with Structs inside of Arrays as well.  This also doesn't deal with an empty Arguments.Key, or fail gracefully on a cflock timeout, but should get you started.

Additionally, those that want to comment that cflock isn't required, please read the [ColdFusion cflock docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cc4.html) first.

**Simplified, but may provide inaccurate results in extremely rare conditions**

Doing an `IsDefined` inline in your code will provide the opportunity for false positives, however having the `IsDefined` inside a udf or cfc method reduces this risk greatly to the point it may not need be a consideration.  If you're happy to take that chance then you can simplify the function using `IsDefined` as Peter Boughton suggests.

```
<cffunction name="Exists" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean">
    <cfargument name="Key" required="true" type="string">

    <cflock scope="session" type="readonly" timeout="3">
        <cfset local.Exists = IsDefined("Session." & Arguments.Key)>
    </cflock>

    <cfreturn local.Exists>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: _"Hopefully the amount of code in this function will justify why a helper function would be useful"_ - nope, it just makes me think you're a lunatic. :)

Comment: What does your code do that `<cfoutput>#isDefined('Session.data.log.deep')#</cfoutput>` doesn't?

Comment: @PeterBoughton 1. Locks the Session scope 2. Doesn't return false values. e.g. add `<cfset Variables.Session.data2=1` test `<cfoutput>#isDefined('Session.data2')#</cfoutput>`  that returns `YES` even though `data2` doesn't exist in the Session scope.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that stupidity. :/ (Has been fixed in Railo, which I use exclusively now.)

Comment: btw, nothing in that link says why to lock the session scope for reading. (Yes, I see the Application/isdefined example, but no actual explanation is given and I never trust example code from Adobe. The old scope corruption issue doesn't apply any more; it wouldn't surprise me if that documentation was simply copy-pasted from previous versions.)

Comment: @PeterBoughton You're suggesting it's copy/pasted from CF 4.5? A non-Adobe post about the shared scope issues: http://blog.bullamakanka.net/2009/12/coldfusion-shared-scopes-and-race.html which unfortunately is truncated, but one of the comments has "With ColdFusion's move to Java the reading and writing to memory has become atomic, which means that there aren't system memory allocation errors (buffer overflows, etc). What it doesn't mean is "everything is now thread safe." The system might not error, but your application likely will unless you concern yourself with threaded programming."

Comment: Wayback has a non-truncated version of [that blog post and comment](https://web.archive.org/web/20100117161916/http://blog.bullamakanka.net/2009/12/coldfusion-shared-scopes-and-race.html)...

Answer (score 4):

if you are checking to see if key "Test" exists in the session struct, try something like this:

```
<cffunction name="Exists" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean" >
    <cfargument name="Key" required="true" type="String" />

    <cfreturn StructKeyExists(session, arguments.Key) />
</cffunction>


<cfif Exists("Test") >
 ....
</cfif>
```

Another concept, or two, since you are looking for a struct within the session would be:

```
<cffunction name="Exists" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean" >
    <cfargument name="Key" required="true" type="String" />

    <cfreturn (structKeyExists(session, listFirst(arguments.Key,"."))
                AND structKeyExists(session[listFirst(arguments.Key,".")], listLast(arguments.Key, "."))) />
</cffunction>

<cfif Exists("data.Test") >
....
</cfif>
```

and

```
<cffunction name="Exists" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean" >
    <cfargument name="struct" required="true" type="String" />
    <cfargument name="Key" required="true" type="String" />

    <cfreturn (structKeyExists(session, arguments.struct)
                AND structKeyExists(session[arguments.struct], arguments.key)) />
</cffunction>

<cfif Exists("data", "Test") >
 ....
</cfif>
```

Hope all this helps point you in the right direction, good luck!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "session" scope exists no matter what (even if it's not being used) so your "isDefined" is unnecessary.

Comment: I can't remember the last time I built an app (vs. something like an API) that didn't use session management.

Comment: But what I am trying to access is, within Session I have again a Struct Named Data and want to test if Session.Data has a Certain key or not. So please check my question again.

Comment: I added a couple more concepts, hope they help.

Answer (score 1):

As Al Everett mentioned above, I don't remember the last time I had an app that didn't have session enabled. I guess if you can't be sure of that, then it makes sense to see if Session exists.  My code for this would include:

```
<!--- in the application.cfc --->
<cffunction name="onSessionStart" output="false">
    <!--- default session structure, you can also add default values to the data
         structure here to ensure they exist later --->
    <cfset session.data = {} />
</cffunction>

<!--- then in code use structKeyExists instead of a whole new function --->
<cfif structKeyExists(session.data, myKey)>

<!--- if you really wanted the "exists" function --->
<cffunction name="dataKeyExists" returntype="boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="key" required="true" />
    <cfreturn structKeyExists(session.data, arguments.key) />
</cffunction>
```

Depending on what's going on, I might choose to pass in the session to maintain encapsulation. But it doesn't always make sense to be a slave to OO and introduce complexity just for the sake of maintaining a pattern. Passing in the session structure *and* evaluating the key is really just a big workaround to using the "structKeyExists" function.

I also dislike having a function called "exists" because it tells me nothing about what it's really evaluating. I'd assume a function like that was like "isDefined" and more generic than just testing for a key in a specific structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfif structkeyexists(session, "data") and structkeyexists(session["data"], key)>
...
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call `<cfif isNull(session.data.fromdate)>`

If the key `data` does not exist in `session` it will not throw, just returns false.